# Using helium with urban airpush in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to create a sample app for Android which can have push notification feature using urban airpush. Urban airpush provides 2 options for push notifications 1. C2DM 2. Helium

https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Android+Getting+Started

As Google do not allow accounts for C2DM now, I am left with helium option only.

So I start with sample helium push project provided by UA

https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+Android%3A+Helium+Push

This is what my airshipconfig.properties look like

```
developmentAppKey = AY1v8U6WQQOJMyNAkv2VDA 
developmentAppSecret = -VwPeOUPTqiX_llY7uvPtg
#productionAppKey = Your Production App Key
#productionAppSecret = Your Production Secret

#transport is "c2dm", "helium" or "hybrid".
#note: the helium and hybrid transports are premium features.
#for complete pricing information, see http://urbanairship.com/pricing/

transport = helium

c2dmSender = myemailid@gmail.com
inProduction = false

iapEnabled = false

# 2 = Log.VERBOSE; 3 = Log.DEBUG; 4 = Log.INFO;
# 5 = Log.WARN; 6 = Log.ERROR; 7 = Log.ASSERT;
developmentLogLevel = 3
productionLogLevel = 6
```

And added these 2 lines in MainActivity OnCreate

```
PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
Logger.info("My Application onCreate - App ID " + prefs.getPushId());
```

But nothing seems to work according to the tutorial

1. prefs.getPushId() is returning null, so I cannot test APID specific alerts
2. UA allows me to send the broadcast alert but it is not being received by the app
3. Does use of helium need GCM or C2DM registration
4. Can I use helium with free account, the site says pro feature are available for first 45 days.

It seems I am missing a lot of things here and the documentation is not complete. If anyone has used UA with helium, please suggest how to create a sample app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing one major step, that is we need to register separately to use helium with free account  https://go.urbanairship.com/apps/free-trial/

1. prefs.getPushId() is returning null, so I cannot test APID specific alerts

   A. It started working fine after the registration
2. UA allows me to send the broadcast alert but it is not being received by the app

   A. A broadcast is sent only to registered devices
3. Does use of helium need GCM or C2DM registration

   A. No
4. Can I use helium with free account, the site says pro feature are available for first 45 days.

   A. Yes, need to fill the form  https://go.urbanairship.com/apps/free-trial/

Comment: do you have any tutorail for android where UA works as push notifications. I need to integrate in my app.